# iOS app rejected when using GoogleTagManager

Tags: ios, google-tag-manager

We submitted an iOS app which was rejected because of private API calls to

dispatchTime
setDispatchTime

Narrowing down the library that calls these functions, its seem its GoogleTagManager v3, which depends on GoogleAnalytics is the culprit, we were using an older version but even the latest 3.17 has a call to this function.

v5 of GTM is available via CocoaPods, which seems to have removed the call and we will start porting to this version, but seems odd cant find anyone else with this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Google Tag Manager isn't calling a private API, but an internal class in Google Tag Manager has a selector with the same signature. We've seen several occurrences of this with Google Tag Manager, and there are other libraries reporting similar rejections (https://openradar.appspot.com/28252227).

You can contact app review and appeal the rejection, informing them that Google Tag Manager is using dispatchTime as the name of a dynamic property of a subclass of NSManagedObject. Apple may allow your app through based on this explanation. As you've noticed, the new version of Google Tag Manager doesn't have this class, but contacting Apple may be the fastest resolution for you.